# remove n+1 row from a df

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe

```
number  time     td
1       1        1
1       1        11
1       2        2
1       10       9
1       14       10
2       1        1
2       11       10
2       15       20
2       15       21
2       16       21
2       17       21
2       18       21
```

If current td > 10 I need to remove row n+1 then move to row n+2 and repeat this step

result

```
number  time     td
1       1        1
1       1        11
1       10       9
1       14       10
2       1        1
2       11       10
2       15       20
2       16       21
2       18       21
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------+----+---+
|number|time|td |
+------+----+---+
|1     |1   |1  |
|1     |1   |11 |
|1     |2   |2  |
|1     |10  |9  |
|1     |14  |10 |
|2     |1   |1  |
|2     |11  |10 |
|2     |15  |20 |
|2     |15  |21 |
|2     |16  |21 |
|2     |17  |21 |
|2     |18  |21 |
+------+----+---+
```

```
scala> :paste

df
.withColumn("rno",monotonically_increasing_id)
.withColumn("isdeleted",when(
        !(when(lag($"td",1).over(Window.orderBy($"number".asc)) > 10, true).otherwise(false)===true && $"rno" % 2 === 0),
        false
    )
    .otherwise(true)
)
.filter($"isdeleted" === false)
.drop("isdeleted","rno")
.show(false)
```

Output

```
+------+----+---+
|number|time|td |
+------+----+---+
|1     |1   |1  |
|1     |1   |11 |
|1     |10  |9  |
|1     |14  |10 |
|2     |1   |1  |
|2     |11  |10 |
|2     |15  |20 |
|2     |16  |21 |
|2     |18  |21 |
+------+----+---+
```